# If I try Lubuntu and then remove it can I expect my normal Ubuntu to be safe and unchanged?

Tags: lubuntu

If I install lubuntu-desktop to try Lubuntu and then later remove it, will my normal Ubuntu  be safe, unchanged and uncluttered?

Comment: why not try it in a virtual machine (virtualbox) or use it from a liveusb stick.

Answer (score 3):

It is indeed possible to fully retain your Ubuntu desktop after removing it. But when you remove (or purge) the lubuntu-desktop after installing, chances are, the applications installed by Lubuntu will still be left behind.

Check the following question on which applications to remove to get rid of Lubuntu apps:

- [How to completely remove desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73993/how-to-completely-remove-desktop)

Also, go through the entire command because it might remove applications which you might wish to keep.

Comment: -1, that link's instructions won't work properly for 11.10 and gtk3.

Comment: @jrg I checked the first line under the title and it read like this "Note, this applies only to Ubuntu 11.10 (Oneiric)." Moreover, the commands were updated fairly recently. "Last updated 10/14/11 01:12" I can't vouch for the fullest safety and security for using those commands but I did use a variant of these commands just a week ago and they worked pretty fine.

Comment: @jokerdino thanks, but that could remove too many things I wanted, and manually removing each package would be tedious. It's unfortunate the package manager can't handle this itself.

Comment: @jrg Updated the answer. If the linked answer is wrong, you should be downvoting that one too. :)